# Enable GestureRegnizer on UIImageView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScrollView` with some `UIImageView` inside. The user can add some picture from his library or directly with his camera, and the picture picked are shown inside a `UIScrollView`.

I would like that the user can delete an `UIImageView` (identified by tag, where tag = index of image in my array), but I can't verify which `UIImageView` is tapped! Only the `UIScrollView`...

Someone has an idea how could I do it ?

**EDIT 1:**

If I used this, I can check the tap on UIScrollView

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singlTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(testGesture:)];
            singlTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
            [self.imagesScrollview addGestureRecognizer:singlTap];
```

Comment: Show the code you're using

Comment: How are you adding the imageViews in scrollview and what is the name of your scrollview and what name are you using to add image view in scrollview

Answer (score 0):

With your current code you would need to iterate through the subviews of the scroll view and 'hit test' each one to see which the tap was over.

Alternatively, add a tap gesture to each image view (instead of one to the scroll view). Then, when the tap is recognised you will have direct access to the image view via the `gesture.view`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just set tag for each imageView and then in handler

```
- (void)testGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

    NSLog(@"%i", img.tag);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the imageView instead of the scrollView, when you add it to the scroll:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singlTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(testGesture:)];
            singlTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
            [self.imageToAdd addGestureRecognizer:singlTap];

- (void) testGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*) sender
{
    int tag = sender.view.tag;
    // do your process here.
}
```

Comment: Yes, but when I do this, I can't get the event... I don't know why! Like subviews on UIScollView are not touchable

Comment: in this case you need to subclass `UIScrollView` and override `touchesBegan`. and you should call: `[self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` same goes for `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, and `touchesCancelled`